# PHP letter looping number to chr

Tags: php

I am trying to turn numbers into letters to create references for rows.

I have:

```
public static function references($idx) {
    $str = '';

    $i = ceil($idx/25);

    if(65+$idx > 90) {

    } else {
        $str = chr(65+$idx);
    }
    return $chr;
}
```

But I don't know where to go from here.

Valid outputs would be:

first item: A
28th item: AB

### ...

Input is an index that comes in from a loop, i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3 etc

Comment: Please show us your input, your output now and your expected output

Comment: But what do you expect to be the output if you input 0 or 1 or 5 ?

Comment: its working fine only na bhai. https://eval.in/266838

Comment: @Rizier123 Output to be expected is A, B,C .... AA, AB, AC ... AAA, AAB...ARB....

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
public static function references($n)
{
    $r = '';
    for ($i = 1; $n >= 0 && $i < 10; $i++) {
        $r = chr(0x41 + ($n % pow(26, $i) / pow(26, $i - 1))) . $r;
        $n -= pow(26, $i);
    }
    return $r;

}
```